# zsh history expansion is missing a whitespace

Tags: zsh

History expansion of zsh always eats the first whitespace after the command. Here is an example:

```
$ zsh -df
$ echo hello world
hello world
$ ^[space]
echohello world
zsh: command not found: echohello
```

The issue also exists if I bind magic-space to the space key and use inline expansion.

If I do this with `echo  hello world` (two spaces between echo and hello) it keeps one and the command works.

I'm on Fedora 34 but this happens also on Fedora 15. What do I need to configure to get this working?

Comment: What is the command `^[space]` doing? If I do this in zsh on MacOS, I get `zsh: substitution failed`

Comment: `[space]` might just be a placeholder for a literal space in the question. Using `^ ` reproduces the issue.

Comment: `^` performs *substitutions* on the previous command, in this case replacing the first space with the empty string before attempting to execute the result. What do you *want* to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not missing a space; you are intentionally *replacing* the space with the empty string. `^` is used to make substitutions in the previous command.

```
% echo hello world
hello world
% ^hello^goodbye
echo goodbye world
goodbye world
```

Without the second `^`, it replaces the pattern with an empty string.

Comment: Yes I used it wrong. Was a misinterpretation in combination with the magic-space function. Thanks